# Prototype to slice an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

Suppose I have an object -

```
{ id: 1,
  name: "Alice",
  color: "red"
}
```

now I want to slice this object according to one of its properties  -

for example , if I chose the property `id` - the object would become to - `{id: 1}`.

Is there any prototype method for that among javascript or angular or underscore frameworks (please DON'T implement it in your answer , I know how to implement it , I just looking for an prototype method) ?

Comment: [Do you see one?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: No I don't , that's why I ask here

Comment: you can write your own, I can give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
Object.prototype.slice_param = function(obj, param){
  for(p in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && p !== param){
       delete obj[p];
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
Object.prototype.slice_param(yourObject, theParamYouWantToKeep);
```

Or use [Underscore's pick method](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) or [Lodash's pick method](https://lodash.com/docs#pick)

Answer (score 1):

It's not prototype, but seems it's that you are looking for 
https://lodash.com/docs#pick